# AVG Access Denied warning when running the simplest C++ program

Tags: c++, g++, iostream, antivirus

I am running a very simple C++ program:

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char **args) {

}
```

I go to the command prompt and compile and run:

```
g++ whatever.cpp
a.exe
```

Normally this works just fine.  It compiles fine, but when I run it it says Access Denied and AVG pops up telling me that a threat has been detected `Trojan Horse Generic 17.CKZT`.   I tried compiling again using the Microsoft Compiler (cl.exe) and it runs fines.  So I went back, and added:

```
#include <iostream>
```

compiled using g++ and ran.  This time it worked fine.

So can anyone tell me why AVG would report an empty main method as a trojan horse but if the iostream header is included it doesn't?

UPDATE:

I added a return statement to the main method and now I find that I only get the error if I return 0.  Any other return value and it seems to work fine.

What's going on here?

Comment: In my experience anti-virus software is a losing proposition in general, and *completely* unacceptable on a development machine.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but from what I understand, currently Avast! Antivirus and NOD32 have better heuristic engines than AVG.

Comment: Great answer here as to why your C++ program is labeled a virus by AVG: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17431911/445131

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You're not the first person to encounter false positives by antivirus software.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/bugs/TheCaseOfEvilWinMain.aspx)

What probably happened is that the antivirus heuristics tripped up on the standard runtime libraries present in your programs, since malware uses them as well. Of course, legitimate software uses them too! The fact that it didn't trip up on `iostream` probably means that `iostream` isn't very popular among malware writers.

Comment: Thanks, since I am just starting in C++ it is good to know that an error like that is not because of something stupid I have done.

Comment: LOL. Nope. It's because of something stupid that *someone else* has done. And it's not exactly a kind problem for a beginner either. Thank God for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to overcome the problem as fast as possible,
just put the folder of the executables into AVG's whitelist.

My preferred steps:

1. For safety's sake, you should send your executable 
   to an online virus/malware scanner like these:

   - www.virustotal.com : VirusTotal - Free Online Virus and Malware Scan
   - virusscan.jotti.org/en : Jotti's malware scan
2. if they report '**false positive**', then insert the path of the compiled executables 
   into AVG's **whitelist**,
   so it doesn't scan that folder.
   I'm not conversant with AVG,
    but every antivirus
   has an option to exclude files from scan.
3. If you're brave enough, debug the executable and find the causing call.
4. An alternative solution may be to virtualize a lightweight linux system,
   install gcc (with g++, of course) on it, and use that "g++ dedicated environment"
   to
   develop your commandline apps.

---

*// The 1st step is a sum-up of [this conversation](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.mingw.user/33193).* 
*// If you send me the source and the 'infected' executable that you compiled, then I'll check it.* 
*// The missing `return` statement in the (C++) `main` function means `returns 0`.*

Comment: A good answer, but this seems like extreme overkill for the question asked.

Comment: :) yes, you're maybe right.. but exactly what can charm away the 'malicious' stuff? what makes such an effect through #include <iostream>? what is it? Or this is an other question?

Comment: Note: It solved my problem by added my folder to AVG like `Menu -> Settings -> General -> Exceptions` here browse for the folder and checkmark it. You are done.

Comment: This should be accepted answer if you want quick solution, instead of understanding as in accepted answer.