# VSC, its powershell, and C

Tags: c, windows, powershell, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a C language `printf` command in VSC.

The name of the .c file is `main.c`, so in Powershell I type `gcc main.c` and a executable file with name `a.exe` is generated.

Now I type `.\a.exe`, and press enter, and then I get an error (see below), and 2 seconds later my exe file is deleted by McAfee antivirus, as antivirus claims it's a virus.

Here is the error:

```
Program 'a.exe' failed to run: Access is denied
At line:1 char:1
+ .\a.exe
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Now more interesting thing, before that, the code which I am trying to execute is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    
    printf("  hello hahahahhahahahahhahahahahahahhahahahaha  ");
    /* code */

    return 0;
}
```

If I add **`getchar();`** just before `return 0;`, the code executes perfectly!

Please help, I have just started learning coding and in C.

Comment: That's a false-positive from your anti-virus software. You can try disabling it for a few moments while you compile and run your code. Maybe update virus signature files?

Comment: Agree with @pmg here, but you can create and run console apps directly in PowerShell. Though I know that is not your point here. Yet since you are learning, it might just prove interesting practice. See, this... [How To Write a Console Application in PowerShell with Add-Type](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/how-to-write-a-console-application-in-powershell-with-add-type). So, mess with this approach to see if you get the same errors.

Comment: @pmg i already contacted my antivirus helpdesk, and already checked, antivirus is not the reason behind its failure,

Comment: @postanote thanks for your suggestion, but a crappy software feels like irritation to me. if you know someone plz help me

Comment: @Nikhil read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987712/why-does-avgantivirus-detect-an-executable-produced-from-dev-c-as-a-virus and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-antivirus/antivirus-false-positives-negatives and https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB85567

Answer (score 0):

Q: why do you have to insert a `getchar()` to see the output from `printf()`?

A: the characters output by the `printf()` are left in the output stream.
To have the characters immediately displayed on the terminal, add a `\n` at the end of the `format` string, similar to:

```
printf("  hello hahahahhahahahahhahahahahahahhahahahaha  \n");
```

Or even better:

```
printf("%s\n", "  hello hahahahhahahahahhahahahahahahhahahahaha  ");
```

in general, outputting data will stay in the output stream buffer until some action forces the data to be passed on to the terminal.

There are several actions that forces the data.

1. an input statement, like `getchar()`
2. calling `fflush( stdout );`
3. overflowing the stdout buffer
4. exiting the program.
5. outputting a newline (`\n`)

Comment: i got your point, but what i am saying is my vsc was running just fine, but then suddenly it started this error, i am not sure of the reason behind it, it used to run even a simple c program with just c,
i am a noob, as i went to vsc in microsoft they told me to come here, so ia sked on stack overflow

Comment: also thanks for these i will take a note of these methods