# C++ program I created is being flagged as insecure by Windows

Tags: c++, exe

I created a game in C++ but when someone downloads it the game is flagged as unsafe and windows tries to block it. How do I fix this? The file is a .exe program.

Comment: Report it as a false positive: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission

Comment: Question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987712/why-does-avgantivirus-detect-an-executable-produced-from-dev-c-as-a-virus), I think you might find a solution with that

Comment: @Gaston That questions relates to antivirus software and my game isn't actually being flagged by antivirus software just the actual windows 10 security.

Comment: Which is just a different antivirus software. The only difference is that it's made by MIcrosoft.

Comment: @P10 Flagged by Windows HOW exactly? Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: Did you sign your executable?

Comment: All software downloaded from the internet will trigger a security warning, signing your code will reduce the severity of the warning and show your name in the warning message